# Read protocol buffer files in apache beam

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a bunch of protobuff files in GCS and I would like to process them through dataflow (java sdk) and I am not sure how to do that.

Apache beam provides AvroIO to read avro files

```
 Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(new File("schema.avsc"));
 PCollection<GenericRecord> records =
     p.apply(AvroIO.readGenericRecords(schema)
                .from("gs://my_bucket/path/to/records-*.avro"));
```

Is there anything similar for reading protobuff files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Might this be what you are looking for?

https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/protobuf/ProtoCoder.html

It seems to have a sample code fragment contained within.

Comment: Yes, I need protocoder but it does not work with Text.IO and couldn't get working with any other IO available

Comment: Can you update the question with what you tried relative to the ProtoCoder class described in the above link.  When you say it didn't work, what was the error?